# Neo4j - apoc.algo.dijkstra - shortest path from a to b, but via c, d, e etc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dijkstra

Hi I am experimenting with routing using neo4j but I am struggling with adapting apoc.algo.dijkstra. I don’t just want to go from A to B, but actually go from A to B via C, whilst taking into account a weighting on the link.

The A-B query is...

```
MATCH  (startNode:road_node {id:'59030214550942348742a27d'}), (endNode:road_node {id:'59030215550942348742a610'})
call apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'ROADLINK', 'min_travel_time') YIELD path, weight
return path, weight/60
```

I tried a few ways of including a via c but can't get it to work... for example

```
MATCH  (startNode:road_node {id:'59030214550942348742a27d'}), (endNode:road_node {id:'59030215550942348742a610'})
call apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'ROADLINK', 'min_travel_time') 
with path, weight
MATCH (startNode)-[*]-(via:road_node {id:'59030215550942348742a666'})-[*]-(endNode)
return path, weight
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to route from A to B via C, whilst taking into a count a weighting on the links, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just invoke the Dijkstra algorithm twice, using `via` as the end node in the first invocation, and then as the start node in the second. The result will have 2 sub-paths and 2 sub-weights (divided by 60).

```
MATCH (start:road_node {id:'59030214550942348742a27d'}), (end:road_node {id:'59030215550942348742a610'}), (via:road_node {id:'59030215550942348742a666'})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, via, 'ROADLINK', 'min_travel_time') YIELD path, weight
WITH end, via, path AS p1, weight/60 AS w1
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(via, end, 'ROADLINK', 'min_travel_time') YIELD path, weight
return p1, path AS p2, w1, weight/60 AS w2;
```